# Python float conversion with decimals

Tags: python

I was codding in python and i noticed something strange. Can you help me ?

```
a = int(float("37.90") * 100)
b = int(float("17.90")* 100)
print (a) #3790
print (b) #1789
```

I was expecting the same behavior in both operations, such as 1790 and 3790.

Comment: The following code outputs the intended results of 3790 and 1789.

Comment: Nah, the code block was just badly formatted. I fixed that, you can see how to indicate a code block using back ticks by looking at the [edit].

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: A float consists of a number of bits. When and how the rounding kicks in w.r.t. precision depends on the values. "Since at least 2000, almost all machines use IEEE 754 binary floating-point arithmetic, and almost all platforms map Python floats to IEEE 754 binary64 “double precision” values."